# Delete the story board and this error show in all project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Can any one help me ? All Xcode projects not work

> 2019-02-13 09:59:57.894875+0300 mmmm[3449:122460]  -
>   [I-ACS036001] Analytics screen reporting is disabled.
>   UIViewController transitions will not be logged. 2019-02-13
>   09:59:58.078349+0300 mmmm[3449:122461] 5.16.0 -
>   [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.50500000 started
>   2019-02-13 09:59:58.094858+0300 mmmm[3449:122461] 5.16.0 -
>   [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the
>   following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see
>   goo.gl/RfcP7r) 2019-02-13 09:59:58.495976+0300 mmmm[3449:122467]
>   [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301)
>   [C1.1:2][0x7fcd43702f00] get output frames failed, state 8196
>   2019-02-13 09:59:58.496111+0300 mmmm[3449:122467] [BoringSSL]
>   nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7fcd43702f00]
>   get output frames failed, state 8196 2019-02-13 09:59:58.496497+0300
>   mmmm[3449:122467] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57 2019-02-13
>   09:59:58.496575+0300 mmmm[3449:122467] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57

Please check below error:

[image]

Comment: post whole error description

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: all error in image

Comment: Have you check your storyboard I think you lost all outlet connections of ur controller ?

Comment: Why you are deleting storyboard ? If you don't want to use storyboards, then you need to manually set the rootview controller of the window property in your didfinish launching method

Comment: show me how can I check it ?@CodeChanger

Comment: I just delete storyboard from one project then all projects not work @iOSTeam

Comment: @MidhunMP just delete it by mistake

Comment: @jon: Please copy the crash log and paste it in your question. The reason for the crash can't be identified from that image.

Comment: @jon: Check whether the main storyboard is present in your project. If present click on it and on the left pane of xcode check whether your targets are selected there or not. It should be selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

Check in info.plist file have key with name **Main storyboard file base name** have value  **Main**. It's used to at launch time which storyboard used. So, if the storyboard deleted from app then remove that Key with it's value. And Have any other storyboard with different name then replace the value with new storyboard name.

Comment: Can you share reason for the crash in your question.

Comment: **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle**   are you getting this reason for crash ?

Comment: **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:** you can find your exact crash reason after this text. Share this in youe question.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the Main.storyboard you need to delete the "Main storyboard file base name" key in the info.plist.

If you really want to delete the storyboard then you need to initialise the window yourself in the AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have select correct storyboard in project settings.

> Goto > Project Settings > Genral > Main Interface

Please refer below screenshot for reference.

[image]